# Blazor WASM publish on IIS => memory access out of bounds , Error loading ICU asset

Tags: iis, out-of-memory, blazor-webassembly

Since the last Visual Studio Preview update to 16.9.0 Preview 1.0 I get the following error from the IIS-Server in our local network:

[image]

On my local machine everything works fine with the IIS Express integrated in Visual Studio. But when I publish the blazor.server project to the IIS-Server in our network I get this message when I try to access the page. So it doesn't start at all

When I jump to the rows mentioned in the message I get the following code snipets

[image]

[image]
[image]
Client-Project-File

[image]
Server-Project-File

Any Idea what could be the cause?

Update 07.12.20 21:40: I just tried to access the webpage directly on the server using "localhost" or "127.0.0.1" and it works without any problems.
If I try to access the page from the same browser-instance using the IP-Address "192.168.50.3" I get the same error as from remote clients

Comment: I am sorry that I have not reproduced your problem based on the information you provided. If you create a Blazor WASM template project, can it be successfully deployed in IIS? I have to know if this is a Blazor WASM project problem or IIS problem.

Comment: Yes, a fresh project can be successfully deployed on the IIS. I stopped searching for a solution to fix my project, It seems something got completely messed up during the update. I just started a new WASM templated project and copied everything from the old project into the new and voila, it works. Thank you for your efforts in helping me